# Why I can't scrape that large XML file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know why this code doesn't do the job? It works perfectly when I want to scrape smaller files with data from a certain date e.g only from 2017 but not with this one. Is this file too big or something? There's no error or anything like that. Every time I run this script but with mentioned smaller file It takes about 30 seconds to download everything and save into a database so there are no mistakes in code I think. After running the script I'm just getting "Process finished with exit code 0" and nothing more.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from app import db
from models import CveData
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


url = "https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.xml"
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

xml = BeautifulSoup(r, 'xml')
vuln = xml.findAll('Vulnerability')

for element in vuln:
    note = element.findAll('Notes')
    title = element.find('CVE').text 

    for element in note:
        desc = element.find(Type="Description").text
        test_date = element.find(Title="Published")

        if test_date is None:
            pass
        else:
            date = test_date.text
            data = CveData(title,date,desc)
            try:
                db.session.add(data)
                db.session.commit()
                print("adding... " + title)

            # don't stop the stream, ignore the duplicates
            except IntegrityError:
                db.session.rollback()
```

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code, see what's going wrong.

Comment: I would never ask a question here without debugging my code. I still can't find any solution that's why I'm here. Even if I appreciate your response, I think it's pointless.

Comment: Hey @Vicaris2code, so much of what people will ask next will be things you likely already found out while debugging. Things like, where in your code path did it take a wrong turn for instance? Does the code ever get inside your try statement for instance?

Comment: Hi @Aaron, It looks like my code fails right at opening the file (but without error, just like it can't manage that size of file) because absolutely nothing happens. That's why I asked if it's too big or something. Also, this code can't be wrong or anything because it works fine with different URLs  fore example with this one: https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems-cvrf-year-2019.xml

Comment: Do you mean it fails here: `r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`, and by fails you mean the code no longer executes after that line? Like if you put a print statement after it, it doesn't get there?

Comment: Dude, that's a 171MB XML file. You may need to set some timeouts and make sure you have enough memory to eat it. Maybe first just try fetching and saving local to ensure that you are able to successfully download. Then test whether you can read/parse that local file with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I seriously doubt that is the issue, while it might be true that in order to run it that kind of tolerance will need to be put in there, those types of errors would cause, well, errors. Exit 0 is a successful exit code. My guess is the problem will end up being something like the large xml document doesn't have any `Vulnerability` elements in it for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the file that you said didn't work, and the one you said did and ran these two greps with different results:

```
grep -c "</Vulnerability>" allitems-cvrf-year-2019.xml
21386

grep -c "</Vulnerability>" allitems.xml
0
```

The program is not stopping on opening the file, it is running to completion. You aren't getting any output because there are no `Vulnerability` tags in the xml file. (Now my grep is not technically accurate, as I believe there could be spaces in the Vulnerability closing tag, but I doubt that is the case here.)

Comment: I'm afraid that you're right. Thank you very much for help. I must have missed something.